# Access the value of a pandas datetime Timestamp in multiple rows - syntax?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a columns of dates that I need to be able to access the value of in a logical operation.  I can do this easily for 1 row, but I can't figure out the syntax to let me look at all rows.

I am trying to find all values withing a time range and in a certain location

```
Y=x.loc[xx.timestamp[:].month<7 and xx.timestamp[:].month>2 and xx.Area == 'GBK']
```

But the 'timestamp' part does not work (my row is labelled 'timestamp').  So, trouble shooting:

access 1 row

```
xx.timestamp[10]
Out[291]: Timestamp('1977-02-15 00:00:00')
```

access the pandas Timestamp month value of this row

```
xx.timestamp[10].month
Out[292]: 2
```

access Timestamp month value for all rows

```
xx.timestamp[:].month
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

I can access one row, but no more.  What am I missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Series doesn't have an attribute month (even if it's a datetime Series):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('2014-01-01'))

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0   2014-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can wrap the Series as DatetimeIndex which does have a month attribute:

```
In [13]: pd.DatetimeIndex(s).month
Out[13]: array([1])
```

In 0.15.0 there'll be a dt accessor:

```
In [14]: s.dt.month  # 0.15.0+ only
Out[14]:
0    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Note: you can't use `and` with Series or numpy arrays, you need to use `&`:

```
x.loc[(DatetimeIndex(xx.timestamp).month < 7) & (DatetimeIndex(xx.timestamp.month) > 2) & (xx.Area == 'GBK')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  In your example, Why is it that s[0].month works (Out[297]: 1), when s.month or s[:].month does not?  Is it not a series if only one element of a series is called, even though this series is only 1 element long anyway?

Comment: @Ryan an element in the Series is a Timestamp, which *does* have a month attribute.